What is the minimum Pearson sample correlation given a perfect sample rank correlation with no ties?
Let $(X, Y)$ be a random sample of finite size $n$ from a bivariate continuous distribution with unknown parameters $(\rho_{XY},\mu_X,\mu_Y,\sigma_X,\sigma_Y)$. Assume observed values are real numbers and ties occur with probability 0. Let $r_P$ be the sample Pearson correlation, and let $r_S$ be the sample Spearman rank correlation. If $r_S$ = 1, it is easy to see that $r_P$ cannot be less than 0.
Given only the above specifications, is there a lower bound on $r_P$ greater than 0 when $r_S$ = 1? What if we add constraints of a bivariate normal population and/or positive correlation parameter $\rho > 0$?
This is a special case of the general question: "What is the distribution of $r_P$ for fixed ranks without ties?" That would be interesting to know as well, but it's presumably not necessary to answer my much narrower question. Although, huge bonus points if you can tell me whether it is possible to obtain every possible value of $r_P$ in the given range.
Note that my question is specifically about the sample values of these statistics. I'm aware that $r_P$ measures linearity of the population relationship while $r_S$ measures its monotonicity. The relationship between the two parameters under bivariate normality is given here, but that does not answer my question about sample range. Also, while there may be relatively trivial answers to the question if one places extreme constraints on $\rho$ or $n$, say, I'm looking for a more general answer.

The only universal lower bound is $-1.$  And yes, it is possible to obtain any real value between $-1$ and $1$ for the Pearson correlation, no matter what the Spearman correlation might be.  ($n=2$ offers some exceptions, as you will find.)  These facts are demonstrated in the duplicate thread.  There are more threads about this: search for Pearson Spearman answers.

Fair point--the other thread clearly shows I was wrong that $r_P$ could not be negative for perfect $r_S$, which does answer the question as posed. That said, it's not an especially enlightening answer, is it? That and similar threads only give counterintuitive, extreme examples. In retrospect, I suppose I was looking for a more general characterization, which I didn't manage to express well, despite some grasping at the idea toward the end of the post. I shall think upon it and possibly post a more precise question, at the risk of again being shunted into the redundant pile!

@virtuolie Having a question closed as a duplicate isn’t a mark of shame. It means that you are thinking about the same questions that other statisticians care to think about and care to answer (can’t close as a duplicate unless there is an answer, with limited exceptions like posting the same question verbatim after it has been closed as unclear). In fact, I once closed my own question as a duplicate, not deleting it because having another question that can be found via search helps direct people to the (interesting) answer.

@whuber I don't see why your answer in the other thread applies here. You can't have an outlier like $(-a, a)$ if the spearman correlation is exactly 1. I can't quite prove it, but I'm pretty sure the lower limit would be $1/(n-1)$, with 2 outliers like $(-a, 0)$ and $(1, a)$.

@Lukas That is a good point -- but the present question asks for a general bound independent of $n$ and it already notes that the case with a Spearman correlation of $1$ is special.

@LukasLohse Interesting! It can be shown that if the random sample is "broken," i.e., information is gone about which x's are paired with which y's, then the MLE for rho > 0 is r computed on X and Y each sorted separately in the same direction. For rho < 0, it is r on (X, Y) sorted in opposite directions. The MLE maximizes m, the expected number of values in the sorted sample that are in the same position as in the correctly-paired sample. When rho = 0, the correlation between r and m is 1/(n-1); the regression equation predicting r from m is linear with both slope and intercept of 1/(n-1).
